# Howto get livereload working?

Tags: javascript, websocket, gulp, livereload

I'm using `gulp-connect 2.0.6` to try and get livereload working,

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:35729/livereload' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Status line contains embedded null
```

The line that throws that error says,

```
this.socket = new this.WebSocket(this._uri);
```

I pasted all the relative files (`gulpfile.js`, `package.json` etc.) and console output in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/broinjc/05b650114df18df28e18).

Comment: I think it's from a difference in the spec for WebSocket

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, it seems like you were following along with a screencast that I published on getting a D3 environment up and running with auto reload: https://www.tagtree.tv/d3-episode1-environment

I had a look at the gist. Just to make this post easier to read for everyone, I want to pull in the contents of your gulpfile.js:

**Your gulpfile.js**

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
  connect = require('gulp-connect'),
  traceur = require('gulp-traceur'),
  sass = require('gulp-ruby-sass');

gulp.task('connect', function() {
  connect.server({
    livereload: true,
    port: 8005
  });
});

gulp.task('sass', function(){
  gulp.src('./sass/*.scss')
  .pipe(sass())
  .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/css'));
});

gulp.task('watch', function(){
  gulp.watch(['./sass/*.scss'], ['sass']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['connect', 'watch', 'sass']);
```

**Solution**

I don't know if it's strictly necessary, but what I did when I coded up the screencast, is hook up a gulp task from the watch task that calls reload on connect.

**Changing the watch task**

Firstly, you need to change your watch task to look like this. Note that the path uses the path from the [screencast](https://www.tagtree.tv/d3-episode1-environment), but use the correct glob to watch files that should trigger a reload.

```
gulp.task('watch', function(){
    gulp.watch(['./sass/*.scss'], ['sass']);
    gulp.watch(['./dist/**/*.*'], ['reload']);
});
```

**The reload task**

The reload task calls reload on the connect module, which publishes a message on the websocket that causes the files to be reloaded, here's what my reload task looks like:

```
gulp.task('reload', function(){
    gulp.src('./dist/**/*.*')
    .pipe(connect.reload());
});
```

**The final version of the gulpfile.js**

For anyone else having problems with the **[screencast](https://www.tagtree.tv/d3-episode1-environment)**, please have a look at the final version of the **gulpfile**:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    connect = require('gulp-connect'),
    traceur = require('gulp-traceur'),
    sass = require('gulp-ruby-sass');

gulp.task('connect', function(){
    connect.server({
        livereload: true,
        port: 8005
    });
});

gulp.task('reload', function(){
    gulp.src('./dist/**/*.*')
    .pipe(connect.reload());
});

gulp.task('sass', function(){
    gulp.src('./sass/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/css'));
});

gulp.task('traceur', function(){
    gulp.src('./scripts/*.js')
    .pipe(traceur())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/scripts'));
});


gulp.task('watch', function(){
    gulp.watch(['./sass/*.scss'], ['sass']);
    gulp.watch(['./scripts/*.js'], ['traceur']);
    gulp.watch(['./dist/**/*.*'], ['reload']);
});


gulp.task('default', ['connect', 'watch', 'sass', 'traceur']);
```

Comment: I've made those changes and am still getting the same errors. When I save sass I get `[18:53:50] Finished 'sass' after 3.61 ms
[18:53:50] gulp-ruby-sass: directory
[18:53:50] gulp-ruby-sass: write main.css
[18:53:50] Starting 'reload'...
[18:53:50] Finished 'reload' after 1.28 ms` and then the same `null error`

Comment: Where do you get the error? In the browser? Or in your gulp process?